# Parse.FacebookUtils.init gives InvalidCharacterError

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, parse-platform

I'm getting `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<iframe name="fb_xdm_frame_http"/>') is not a valid name.` when I try to run `Parse.FacebookUtils.init`. Init code can be found at https://gist.github.com/ryansmith94/0ff03caf002fa2a8eb8b. Any ideas how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by changing Facebook's sdk.js code at line 46. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1466190186951391